# What is the effect of Service Network Restart

Tags: linux, networking, network-adapter, centos-6

In network configuration file ifcfg-eth0 . There is a field "onboot" if I put onboot=no and restart the service network. Then interface eth0 did not up. If I put onboot=yes it does up the interface after "service network restart" command.

But the description says the field is yes if we want that after reboot the system the interface is automatically up.

So where am I getting wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like it's working exactly as intended if I understand correctly.

With onboot=yes that means you want the interface to be "turned on" when the machine goes through a power cycle.

With onboot=no that means you DON'T want the interface to be "turned on" when the machine goes through a power cycle.

The onboot state is independent of what happens during a service network restart command. If you just want your interfaces to come up or down manually you'll need to do use ifup (interface) or ifdown (interface).

Does this help to clarify?

Comment: No the question is the service network restart command and machine power cycle meant to same for nic card or it is diffiernt. Because I feel that if we restart a service then it first shutdown the goes up. So similar is happening for NIC card like NIC first shutdown and then goes up when we use the service restart. I mean this is a thoguht.Am I thinking in right direction or not? Please help!!!!!!!!